# How to implement mirroring with Ryu controller

Tags: controller, mininet, ryu

I'm trying to implement mirroring with ryu controller. I have one mininet with 2 host (h1 and h2) and 2 switches (s1 and s2), the Ip of the mininet is 192.168.33.10. 
I was wondering if it is possible to reply and forward all the traffic going through the switch s1 to another network with Ip address 192.168.33.11.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

That should be possible, though all I have done thus far is mirror traffic to a local host on my SubNet. I did it using Ryuretic, which is an additional abstraction layer for the Ryu Controller. All you have to worry with is the incoming packet. The operations it offers include fwd, drop, mirror, redirect, and craft.

The Ryuretic backend renders all events to the user as a pkt (a dictionary object), and the contents of the pkt are retrieved by providing the header field of interest (e.g, pkt['srcmac'], pkt['dstmac'], pkt['ethtype'], pkt['inport'], pkt['srcip'], etc.) Using the information from the pkt, the user can choose which fields to match and what action (fwd, drop, redirect, mirror, craft) to take when a match is found.

To install Ryuretic, simply copy the [files] (https://github.com/Ryuretic/RyureticLabs/tree/master/ryu/ryu/app/Ryuretic) to the directory /ryu/ryu/app/Ryuretic. If you installed Ryu, then you already have the /ryu/ryu/app directory. You just need to create the Ryuretic directory and copy the files there.

[Ryuretic Labs](https://github.com/Ryuretic/RyureticLabs/wiki) provides setup instruction and some use cases for implementing security features on SDNs using Ryuretic. It also provides a Mininet testbed for testing your network applications on the VM provided by SDN Hub.

Comment: How can we redirect a packet? There any tutorial for this use case?